# Предоставить доступ к свойствам объекта при вызове метода другого объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть динамически создаваемый объект:

```
obj = new N.make();
```

После создания присваиваю объекту несколько функций:

```
obj.func = function() {
    ...
}
```

Хочу описать эти функции в другом объекте, чтобы не захламлять код, но нужен доступ к свойству `this` этого динамического объекта `obj` из того места, где они описаны. Как такое реализовать? Что-то типа:

```
obj = new N.make();
obj.func = virtual.func;

...

virtual = {
    func: function() {
        this... > Здесь нужен доступ к свойствам объекта "obj"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, ничего особенного делать не нужно: this определяется при вызове функции, а не при создании:

```js
const obj = { foo: 42 };
const functions = { logFoo() { console.log(this.foo); } };

obj.logFoo = functions.logFoo;

obj.logFoo(); // 42
```

Comment: Да, и правда. Странно, у меня сначала выдавало `undefined`.

Comment: Возможно, вы тестировали функцию также и как `functions.logFoo()`, ведь в служебном объекте нет нужных свойств.